# Does forcing with recursively pointed perfect trees add a Turing degree that is minimal over $V$?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, computability-theory, forcing

A tree $T$ on $\omega$ is *recursively pointed* if it is recursive in each of its branches.  We can consider a variant of Sacks forcing where the conditions are recursively pointed perfect trees ordered by inclusion.  Given a $V$-generic filter $G$ for this forcing, we can define the real $x_G = \bigcap_{T\in G} [T]$. 
For every real $x \in V$ we have $x <_\text{T} x_G$.  Given a real $x \in V[G]$ with $x <_\text{T} x_G$, must we have $x \in V$?

Probably the answer to this question is well-known, but I'm afraid I don't see how the proof of the minimality property for Sacks forcing (as given by Jech) might adapt to recursively pointed trees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you two haven't worked this out already, it seems to me that $x_G$ is not minimal as a Turing degree above $V$, but is a minimal $V$ degree.  For the first, since $x_G$ computes $0'$, it follows that $x_G$ is the join of two mutually 1-generic reals, neither of which computes $x_G$ and at least one of which is not in $V$.  However, if $x_G$ computes $x$ and $x$ is not in $V$, then there is an $a$ in $V$ such that $x\oplus a$ computes $x_G$.  This is by the usual minimality argument: $a$ is the degree of the splitting tree for the functional used to compute $x$ from $x_G$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\Phi$ be such that $ x = \Phi^{x_G}$. Since $x\not\ge_T x_G$, it must be that $x_G$ belongs to a tree $T\in V$ with no $\Phi$-splittings. Now given $n$ we can search through $T$ for a string $\sigma$ making $\Phi^\sigma(n)$ converge, and then it must be that $\Phi^\sigma(n)=x(n)$. Thus $x\le_T T$ and so $x\in V$.

(Edited)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?  I can guess the definition of $\Phi$-splitting, but I don't see how to prove what you said.

Comment: Thanks.  Now can you say why the second sentence is true?

Comment: I guess the issue is that $x\not\ge_T x_G$ needs to imply $x\oplus T\not\ge_T x_G$. If all the trees are $A$-recursive for a fixed $A$ then that should be okay, but if $A$ is allowed to vary then you maybe want to have a counting of all the reals in $V$...

Comment: I see, that does seem to be the issue.  The trees have unbounded Turing degrees because I really do want to consider all trees in $V$, and I would like to show that the Sacks real added by this particular forcing notion is minimal over $V$, not just that we can get some real that is minimal over $V$.  But maybe there is some way to show that the case "$x_G \le_\text{T} x \oplus T$ and $x_G \not\le_\text{T} x$" cannot occur in this situation?

Comment: As for "minimal over $V$", would you be okay with weakening the assumption "$x<_T x_G$" to "$x\le_T x_G$ and $x_G\not\in L(x)$"?

Comment: Yes, that would be enough for my application.  Can you prove the weaker version?

Comment: Hmm... Does it make sense to talk about "$V[x]$" (as in, $T\in V$ implies $T\oplus x\in V[x]$)? If so, can I replace $L[x]$ by $V[x]$ in the above? If not, can we perhaps assume $T\in L$?

Comment: One can talk about $V[x]$, but that degree notion is too coarse for what I have in mind.  And I want to force with all the recursively pointed trees in $V$, not just those in $L$.  What I ultimately want is to show is that $\mathbb{R}^V \in L[x_G]$.  Because $\mathbb{R}^V \subset L[x_G]$, one sufficient condition for this would be that the Turing degree of $x_G$ is minimal over $V$ (as in the question,) and another sufficient condition would be that the $L$-degree of $x_G$ is minimal over $V$ (the possibility you raised in the comment before last.)  But a third way would be okay too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15595/discussion-between-bjorn-kjos-hanssen-and-trevor-wilson).