# Recursively Pointed Sacks Forcing and Preserving $\omega_1$

Tags: set-theory, computability-theory, forcing

Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote recursively pointed Sacks forcing. This is forcing with recursively pointed perfect trees ordered by inclusion. A tree $T \subseteq {}^{<\omega}2$ is recursively pointed if and only if for all $f \in [T]$, $T \leq_T f$.

The question is whether $\mathbb{P}$ preserves $\aleph_1$.

From the paper *The Derived Model Theorem II* by Yizhen Zhu which is based on some notes of Woodin (this can be found at http://graduate.math.nus.edu.sg/~g0700513/der.pdf), near the bottom of page 5, it writes "It is a basic property of recursively pointed Sacks forcing that every countable set of ordinals in the generic extension is covered by a countable set in the ground model" This implies that $\aleph_1$ is preserved.

However, I believe that a fundamental property of recursively pointed Sacks forcing is that the generic real $x_G$ has the property that for all $x \in ({}^\omega 2)^V$, $x \leq_T x_G$. Since there are only countably many reals that are Turing reducible to any give real, the ground model reals are countable in the generic extension. Sacks proves a version of this in *Countable Admissible Ordinals and Hyperdegrees* for hyperarithmetic reducibility. Is this fact still true with recursively pointed Sacks forcing?

The following Mathoverflow question [Does forcing with recursively pointed perfect trees add a Turing degree that is minimal over $V$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173484/does-forcing-with-recursively-pointed-perfect-trees-add-a-turing-degree-that-is) also suggest that the generic real for recursively pointed Sacks forcing computes all ground model reals.

Am I misunderstanding something here. It appears that the generic real computing all ground model reals implies $\aleph_1$ is collapse, but the claim from the above paper implies $\aleph_1$ is preserved. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: If $T$ is any recursively pointed tree, then can't we refine it to a smaller tree $T'\leq T$ consisting of (the initial segments of) just one branch? And surely in this case $T'$ is recursively pointed, since $T'$ in this case would be computable from its only branch. So it seems that this forcing, the way you have described it, is atomic? If so, this interpretation of the forcing would make it trivial. Could you clarify?

Comment: I suspect it should be "recursively pointed *perfect* trees."

Comment: That would solve my issue, and I expect that you are correct.

Comment: A question about the cited claim: is it, "given any set of ordinals $X\in V[G]$ such that $V[G]\models$ "$X$ is countable," there is a set of ordinals $Y\in V$ such that $Y\supseteq X$ and $Y$ is countable **in $V$**?" or ". . . **in V[G]**?" If the latter, I don't see how that implies that $\aleph_1$ is preserved.

Comment: @NoahS I think it is countable in $V$. After the quote, the author writes "Hence in $M_\delta$ there exists $q \leq p$ and a countable set a such that $q \Vdash ran(\dot w) \subseteq \hat{a}$ ... since $a$ is countable in $M_\delta$!". It appears that the author is forcing in $M_\delta$, i.e. $M_\delta$ is a the ground model and the author writes $a$ is countable in $M_\delta$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, these should always be perfect trees. I will correct this.

Comment: I'm trying to show that every generic real for recursively pointed Sacks forcing computes every real in the ground model: each perfect set $T$ is Turing equivalent to a strictly order-preserving $f: 2^{<\omega} \to 2^{<\omega}$; in the ground model take a recursively pointed such $f$ and another real $x$, define inductively by letting $g(\emptyset) = f(\emptyset)$ and $g(\sigma \langle i \rangle) = f(\tau \langle x(n) i \rangle)$ where $n$ is the length of $\sigma$ and $i < 2$. Then $g$ is an extension of $f$ s.t. every path computes $x$. So recursively $x$-pointed conditions are dense.

Comment: Sorry. In the above comment: $\tau$ is such that $f(\tau) = g(\sigma)$.